# Web server to easily make a directory accessible over HTTP

Tags: web-server

I'm looking for a program for Windows that can straightforwardly make a directory accessible over HTTP.

Any license, OS or price is fine. Preference for portable programs.

The [same question](https://superuser.com/q/231080/116475) was posted by [Martin R-L](https://superuser.com/users/38883/martin-r-l) but it was closed as off-topic almost 10 years ago.

---

What I have tried:

- [mongoose](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose): worked for a few minutes, then got a "504 Gateway Time-out" error.
- [SimpleHTTPServer](https://github.com/keijack/python-simple-http-server): I'd prefer not to have Python as a requirement.
- [Quickshare](http://houbysoft.com/qs/): their website has disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [HFS](https://www.rejetto.com/hfs/), which was just made for this.

Answer (score 1):

For development or production?

In any case, see the [Big list of http static server one-liners](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255). The gist is from 2013, but the replies and comments are fairly recent.

If you want to set up a webserver with *https* enabled, you can try  PHP- and Docker-based [ddev](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). (Maybe there are easier ways to do this.)

The ddev installer makes creating and correctly installing a self-signed TLS-Certificate easy.
Users will get browser-warnings once, but at least you will have https.